# SVN server and many clients with single hub

Tags: networking

I'm working with SVN server to develop SW.

I have nothing but single dummy hub(5 port).

What I want to do is sharing source FILE on the SVN server so that all developers can work together.

please check my plan to do this...

1. Allocating IP address to all client...

   client1 : 172.20.20.11

   client2 : 172.20.20.12

   client3 : 172.20.20.13

   client4 : 172.20.20.14

   SVN server : 172.20.20.100

   GW : 172.20.20.1

   NETMASK : 255.255.255.0

I'm not sure for the `GW` ans `NETMASK` config....

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netmask is fine, or you could use 255.255.0.0 (and a few others; doesn't matter so long as every machine has the same configuration).

Gateway doesn't matter since you don't have internet access anyhow, set it to 172.20.20.whatever.